# CSS same class after n-th level

Tags: css, css-selectors

**CSS:**

```
.discussionLevel-1 {padding: 20px 0px 20px 70px;}
.discussionLevel-2 {padding: 20px 0 20px 90px;}
.discussionLevel-3 {padding: 20px 0 20px 110px;}
```

I am trying to set every **n>3** to **n=3**.

**Q:** How to use selectors for

```
.discussionLevel-4
.discussionLevel-5
.discussionLevel-6
...
```

etc to be same as `.discussionLevel-3` ?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `:nth-child(n+3)` selector for this. Assuming you have a wrapper div.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/Uv4zw/)**

HTML

```
<div class="discussion">
<div class="discussionLevel-1">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-2">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-3">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-4">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-5">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-6">hi</div>
<div class="discussionLevel-7">hi</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.discussionLevel-1 {padding: 20px 0px 20px 70px;}
.discussionLevel-2 {padding: 20px 0 20px 90px;}

.discussion div:nth-child(n+3) {padding: 20px 0 20px 110px;} 
/*All div after and including div 3*/
```

Comment: Actually if he wanted this than he should opt `.discussionLevel-3 ~ div[class^=".discussionLevel-"]` which I have shared in my answer which is more compatible, as it doesn't use `nth` method

Comment: @Mr.Alien `nth-child` is more comfortable for me in this case.

Comment: Obviously, but more compatibility should be the concern - http://jsfiddle.net/Uv4zw/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-child` there, won't respect your classes though it will do the same job for you... If you are dealing with various elements on the same level than prefer using `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn7q5/)

You haven't provided the DOM so am going with `ul` and `li` here

```
ul li:nth-child(1n) {
    color: red;
}

ul li:nth-child(2n) { /* Targets every 2nd element */
    color: green;
}

ul li:nth-child(3n) { /* Targets every 3rd element */
    color: blue;
}
```

---

Still not sure when I read this *etc to be same as `.discussionLevel-3`* so if you want to target all the elements followed `.discussionLevel-3` on the same level to be applied the styles than you can use `~`

```
.discussionLevel-3,
.discussionLevel-3 ~ div[class^="discussionLevel-"] {
   /* Styles */
}
```